# Registering a Service Worker gives 404 in webpack project

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, service-worker

I have a basic webpack starter project with just html, css and javascript. I am trying to register a service worker with the application but it is constantly giving 404 error in the console saying service worker not found.

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
index.js?15bb:21 Service Worker failed to install TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8080/') with script ('http://localhost:8080/sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with the issue?

I have updated my git repo which is public.
https://github.com/ankitbtanna/service-workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `src/sw.js` is never ingested into the `webpack` asset pipeline, so the `webpack` development server doesn't know how to respond to requests for it.

If your `src/sw.js` is just a static file (like it is right now), then you should put it in the `public/` directory, and your `webpack` configuration will automatically expose it to the development server.

The one wrinkle here is that you'd want to make sure that everything in `public/` is served from your web root `/`, not from `/public/`, because you need the URL for your service worker to be `/sw.js`, not `/public/sw.js`.

You can change your `CopyWebpackPlugin` config to do this:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
  patterns: [{
    from: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
    to: '.', // changed from 'public'
  }],
}),
```

Comment: apologies. I forgot to respond. This worked perfectly fine.